# Очистить консоль python в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, pycharm

Пишу простой алгоритм reinforcement learning, в котором есть простенькая анимация, посредствам вывода в консоль. Так вот, чтобы показать новый кадр анимации, мне надо как-то эту консоль очистить.

Сейчас использую `print(100*'\n')`, но это выглядит не очень красиво из-за прокрутки консоли. Использую PyCharm IDE, если это важно.

Пробовал `os.system('cls')` и `print('\k')` — не работает. Можно ли как-то очищать консоль, чтобы заново выводить в нее новый кадр анимации?

**P.S.** Стоит добавить: кадр -- квадратная матрица размера n, каждый элемент которой -- отдельный символ: =, если клетка пустая, А - если в клетке агент, Е - если в клетке враг. Матрица обновляется и выводится новый кадр. Сейчас n=7. Общее количество кадров заранее не может быть известно.

Comment: Сколько строк выводится в анимации ?

Comment: Добавил информацию в пост.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, для консоли работает метод `os.system('cls')`, который ломается при выводе внутри PyCharm. С другой стороны, прямо внутри PyCharm есть терминал, с которым эта функция работает.

**UPD:** В техподдержке PyCharm посоветовали включить эмуляцию терминала в консоли вывода (делается это в Run|Edit Configurations). С включенной эмуляцией `os.system('cls')` работает нормально и в консоли вывода.